# Unzip a tar.gz file

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm newbie in Pentaho Spoon
I'm trying to unzip a tgz file but I can't find a transformation or job that does it, the closest thing I found was the "Unzip file" job which doesn't let me unzip the tgz file.
Does anyone know whether or not you can unzip a tgz file in Spoon?
In the event that it is not possible.. Do you know any method that comes close?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Shell step in a job to unzip the file using the OS shell script capabilities instead of PDI.